# Http headers to cache a dynamic page

Tags: php, http, header, cache-control

I have a classic html page generated with PHP.

For this page (served from a same URL) we have 2 cases:

1. The user is logged (cookie based) => the page is specific to the user (we display a box with user name + personal information.)
2. The user is not logged in => the page is common to all the user.

How can I set the header to:

- have the most agressive cache (with a max-age of 60).
- avoid mixing pages between users.

Can I replace my present header:

```
header("Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
header("Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Cache-Control: post-check=0, pre-check=0", false);
header("Pragma: no-cache");
```

With this?

```
header('Cache-Control: public, max-age=60');
header('Vary: *');
```

**Edit**: Is it possible (how) to have it Cache-controled private in case "1" and public in case "2"

Answer (score 0):

If login is purely cookie based then you only need a Vary: Cookie header to make it unique to a particular user. The Vary: * should work just as well though.

Comment: Take care! Its not that easy: IE does not cache resources with the Vary header and any fields [but Accept-Encoding and User-Agent](http://code.google.com/speed/page-speed/docs/caching.html)

Comment: If you don't include the Vary header you will have a security issue.  IE simply has no way to handle the caching for this type of setup where the URL is the same but the content varies based on the value of a cookie (ie the user being logged in or not).

Comment: Yea, but I think its the wrong approach to try to solve this with Vary (except for the unlikely case that you have no IE users). A good solution would be to just serve different headers depending on the cases: 1) send headers that prevent caching, 2) send headers to allow caching. No need for Vary in either case.

Comment: You can't just change which HTTP caching headers you send otherwise an intermediate proxy could cache the logged-in page and return it to an unauthenticated user (a security hole).  If the content varies based on a cookie you have absolutely no choice but to use Vary: cookie. Any other attempt to solve the problem will leave security holes open.